# Compiler cannot parse a function call

Tags: c++, function

I have the code that uses `recv` function:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

char *buf = new char[1000];

int main()
{
        SOCKET ConnectSocket;
        addrinfo hints, *result;
        do{
                result = recv(ConnectSocket, buf, 1000, result);
                result = recv(ConnectSocket, buf, 1000, 0);
                std::cout << result << std::endl;
        } while (result > 0);
}
```

I'm going to run that code on windows 8, cygwin. The issue is when I copile that code with `g++ -c mmm.cpp` I got the following error:

```
$ g++ -c mmm.cpp
mmm.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
mmm.cpp:15:49: error: invalid conversion from ‘addrinfo*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   result = recv(ConnectSocket, buf, 1000, result);
                                                 ^
In file included from mmm.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/w32api/winsock2.h:992:34: note: initializing argument 4 of ‘int recv(SOCKET, char*, int, int)’
   WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE int WSAAPI recv(SOCKET s,char *buf,int len,int flags);
                                  ^
mmm.cpp:15:49: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘addrinfo*’ [-fpermissive]
   result = recv(ConnectSocket, buf, 1000, result);
                                                 ^
mmm.cpp:16:44: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘addrinfo*’ [-fpermissive]
   result = recv(ConnectSocket, buf, 1000, 0);
```

What the hell does it mean? First, the compiler told us that it couldn't convert `addrinfo*` to `int` and then it told that it couldn't perform reverse convertion. Does the function `recv(SOCKET, char*, int, int)` exist at all?

Comment: `recv` doesn't take an `addrinfo*` in its signature: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx and it returns an int.

Comment: @jschultz410 Ok, did you read the compiler messages? _error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘addrinfo*’ [-fpermissive]
   result = recv(ConnectSocket, buf, 1000, 0);_ What does it mean?

Comment: "First, the compiler told us that it couldn't convert addrinfo* to int and then it told that it couldn't perform reverse convertion." - What's so special about that? This is completely normal.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Why  does `result = recv(ConnectSocket, buf, 1000, 0);` fail?

Comment: @user3663882: Because `recv` returns an `int`, and `result` is not an `int` (or a compatible type) but a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

The function you are calling is defined as follows:

```
int recv(
  _In_   SOCKET s,
  _Out_  char *buf,
  _In_   int len,
  _In_   int flags
);
```

In the first case you are passing a variable of type `addrinfo*` as 4. argument. This can not be converted to `int` as required by the function definition.

In the second and third case, you assign the return value which is of type `int` to a variable of type `addrinfo*` and this causes another problem.

Comment: Why does `result = recv(ConnectSocket, buf, 1000, 0);` fail? I can't understand...

Comment: @user3663882: `recv` returns an `int`. You try to assign the return value of `recv` to a pointer. An `int` cannot be implicitly converted to a pointer. That's exactly what the error message says. Try the following mini program: `int main() { int* ptr = 0; int i = ptr; }`. It will give you the same error message.